# Check if a worksheet exists

Tags: r, r-googlesheets

How can you check if a certain worksheet with title exist in your spreadsheet, using the googlesheets package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know what the title of the worksheet is, you can check for it this way. Here is a toy example. Load the gapminder test data first:

```
> library(googlesheets)
> gs_gap() %>% gs_copy(to = "Gapminder")
```

This will send you to Google to authenticate. Once you do that, close the browser, and return to R. The worksheets available are stored in `$ws$ws_title`:

```
> gap <- gs_title("Gapminder")
> gap$ws$ws_title
[1] "Africa"   "Americas" "Asia"     "Europe"   "Oceania"
```

So you can check and see if a particular named worksheet is available like this:

```
> ("Africa" %in% gap$ws$ws_title)
[1] TRUE
```

There is more info in the `googlesheets` vignette here which should help you make the connection to your spreadsheet: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googlesheets/vignettes/basic-usage.html